# PUT method not working to update a cell in googlesheets using sheet ab api

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Hello ive been using sheetdb api as my google spreadsheet api and ive been following their documentation on how to do PUT request. However it is not working.

```
function submit(){
  var weight = document.getElementById("weight").value;
  var height = document.getElementById("height").value;
  var IDnum = document.getElementById("IDnum").value;
  var height=height/100;
  height=height*height;
  var calc = weight / height;
  var bmi = calc.toFixed(2);
  alert(bmi);
  fetch("https://sheetdb.io/api/v1/mrdpa17lx93ik/search?sheet=database&id="+IDnum,{
    method: "PATCH",
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        data:{
        "CALCULATED BMI":bmi,
        "duplication":1
      },
      })
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => console.log(data))
    .then((html) => {
      confirm("submitted successfully");
    });
}
```

This is how my code is right now.
It seems that it goes through this whole line of code since confirm("submitted successfully") does appear but when I look at the google spreadsheets the value in the column doesnt update.

Comment: Does your spreadsheet have a sheet called `database` and a column with `id` in its first row? If this is set properly, what do you get with `console.log(data)`? Is it something like `{ updated: <non-zero-number> }`?

Comment: i do have a sheet called database and id is on the first row. 404 error appears on my console

Comment: Please post the full error - edit your question, and add the error. 404 means that something is not found. Can you check if the ID of your document / spreadsheet is correct? Just so we can eliminate that as the source of the 404.